# How to display your media player program to show on volume control on windows 10

Tags: vb.net, popup, windows-10, media-player, volume

i've been trying to make media player to appear in the windows 10 volume control like when using groove music or spotify or even google chrome when you press the volume up or down button in the keyboard a volume control popup appears with the volume slider and the media information with a play/pause , next and previous buttons how can i achieve that if it is available as an api or a library.
i don't have any code because i couldn't find any useful ideas on google.
That's the image i have for the Popup.
[image: Windows 10 Volume Control Popup for groove music]

Comment: Try looking into System Media Transport Controls.
MSDN Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/integrate-with-systemmediatransportcontrols

Comment: Okay i'll look into it , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you need to use the windows 10 SMTC [^](http://Try%20looking%20into%20System%20Media%20Transport%20Controls.%20MSDN%20Link:%20learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/%E2%80%A6)
Samples:

```
    Dim props As MediaItemDisplayProperties = mediaPlaybackItem.GetDisplayProperties()
    props.Type = Windows.Media.MediaPlaybackType.Video
    props.VideoProperties.Title = "Video title"
    props.VideoProperties.Subtitle = "Video subtitle"
    props.VideoProperties.Genres.Add("Documentary")
    mediaPlaybackItem.ApplyDisplayProperties(props)
```

```
    props = mediaPlaybackItem.GetDisplayProperties()
    props.Type = Windows.Media.MediaPlaybackType.Music
    props.MusicProperties.Title = "Song title"
    props.MusicProperties.Artist = "Song artist"
    props.MusicProperties.Genres.Add("Polka")
    mediaPlaybackItem.ApplyDisplayProperties(props)
```

More at: [^](http://Try%20looking%20into%20System%20Media%20Transport%20Controls.%20MSDN%20Link:%20learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/%E2%80%A6)

Comment: Then how does Spotify do it? There must be an API for it.

Comment: @ilovecookiez11 Yep there is an api for it.Check the answer